# Azure EventHub / Azure Monitoring - Create alert when incoming bytes exceed outgoing bytes, preferrably by a certain amount?

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-monitoring

I want to know when my consumer group fails to handle the amount of events coming in into EventHub. Looking at the metrics, I think the symptom is incoming bytes exceed outgoing bytes.

In Azure portal, I only see alert condition when incoming bytes greater than a static number, which is not what I want. Is it even possible to set up condition like this?

Comment: You can do this out-of-the-box in Serverless360 (https://www.serverless360.com/azure-event-hubs-monitoring-management) where you have Threshold/Status monitor which help you achieve to compare the number of incoming bytes exceed outgoing bytes and alert you through the preferred notification channel. Since this is not possible to do right away in the Azure portal, you may try using this.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked Azure Monitor docs and alerts don't seem to support metric comparison.

One solution might be to create an Azure Logic App which can store and remember incoming/outgoing byte values and then compare them on a scheduled basis.

For variable support you can look at - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-variables-store-values

Comment: How can Azure Logic App query the throughput of Azure Event Hub? Is there an API?

Comment: You can add an Event Hubs trigger to consume events. See here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azure-event-hubs